# Ideas in implenting the following entry form in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a very simple data entry form to implement. It looks like this:

[image]

Obviously I have mocked out the actual requirements but the essence is similar.

- Entering a name and clicking history should bring up a pop up pointing to the url '/student/viewhistory/{name}'
- Name and age are required fields
- The sub form (in the mockup) with Class (a drop down, containing the numbers 1 -> 10) and Subject (containing A -> D, say) form a unique pair of values for which a score is required. So, selecting the Class and Subject, entering a score and clicking on Add should 'add' this record for the student. Then the user should be able to click Save (to persist the entry to the database) or be able to add further (class, subject, score) pairs to the entry.

Any ideas how to smartly implement this? (I am coming from a DWH field... so thinking in a stateless manner is slightly foreign to me.) Any help is appreciated.

I would imagine a smart use of jQuery would give a easy solution.

Regards,
Karan

Comment: Just to give a little background... I have already setup the domain model, the repository, and have setup IoC (using Ninject 2.0)

Just having a little difficulty getting my head around this form. Before I go ahead and make my own implementation, I want to ensure I am going in the right direction.

Karan

Comment: +1 for the font used in your example image ;)

Comment: Heh :) Just opened up mspaint for a quick mock up :P :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in that case I'll show you how I've done this on several opportunities: 
First I place a div inside the jquery with empty fields like this:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#classes").append($(
    "<div>" 
    +"   <select name='Student.Classes[0].Class'>"
    +"     <option value='1'>Class 1</option>"
            ....
    +"  </select>"
    +"   <select name='Student.Classes[0].Subject'>"
    +"     <option value='1'>Subject 1</option>"
            ....
    +"  </select>"
    +"  <input name='Student.Classes[0].Score' value='0'/>"
    +"</div>"
    )
);});
```

This div will added to the list of classes when something with the id #add is clicked.

Next I catch the form before the submit and give each entity (Student.Classes in this case) an index starting from 0. Like this:

```
 $("form").submit(function () {
        $("div", "#classes").each(function (i) {
            $(":input, :hidden", this).each(function () {
                $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace(/\[0\]/, "[" + i + "]"));
            });
        });
    });
```

If your are using a ModelBinder that supports sub entities this should end up on the server with a list of Classes within the Student. Of course you can use firebug to see exactly what is being posted to the server.

Hope this gives some direction.

Comment: Building HTML by concatenating JS strings... not what I would recommend.  Surely jQuery can pull in existing inputs and wire them up as needed?

Comment: @bmoeskau
I agree but that isn't the main issue here. Getting the all inputs setup in order in a way the model binder can convert to sub-entities is the tricky part.

Comment: I have marked this as answer because this pushed me in the right direction. I used a partial request to pull pre constructed HTML from server (based on a index variable).

Comment: @KiD0M4N (hard to type your username :) ) If you are building the html within your controller you are breaking the MVC paradigm. Sending the dropdowns in a partial view though sounds like an interesting idea I might try next time I implement something like this.

Comment: I did not build it in the controller... instead I utilized a partial templated view for the same and passed in the index using the Model.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit overkill but you'd most probably benefit from learning about application foundations and scaffolding. I would start here http://sharparchitecture.net/ .
Once you have the basic app set up you could use jquery along with the plugins like

- jquery forms
- jquery Validation

to handle the form up to the submit.
There a quite a few plugins to help with popup window.

How to submit an arbitrary number of sub entities (like the classes of a student in your example) is really a question of your specific server side implementation. This can be done quite elegantly with s#arp architecture but requires some tweaking of the form before submit.

Welcome to the stateless world of web forms! and good luck,
David

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.

I have the Domain Model, Repository, etc setup as of now. However, just having a little difficulty around this particular page.

Any particular solution ideas would be welcome.